# Merging 2 chrome extensions without conflicts with JS files and URLS

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

I made 2 extensions
Extension 1:

```
{ 
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Plug 1",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Plug 1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["file1.js"],
        "matches": ["https://domain1.com/*/files/*"]
    }]
}
```

Extension 2:

```
   {
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "Plug 2",
        "version": "1.0",
        "description": "Plug 2",
        "content_scripts": [{
            "js": ["file2.js"],
            "matches": ["https://domain2.com/*"]
        }]
    }
```

Is there a way to put 2 extensions in 1 extension? I'm having issues because I want file1.js to only match domain1 bot not domain2, an viceversa file2.js only matching domain2 but not domain1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, content_scripts is an array in the manifest.json so you can have multiple objects pointing to different scripts. Just copy the files to the other extension. Then copy the object in the content_scripts array to the manifest.